# search replace multiple words in word doc with excel data

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am trying to populate a word document with data from an excel spreadsheet. However when I run the code below, "sitename" is replaced with with data from cell "B2", "B3" and a number of other cells which i used to replace other words. I only want it to be replaced with cell "B2".

```
Dim results As Workbook
Dim wApp
Dim wDoc
Private Sub populateSite()
    With wDoc
        'Site ID
        .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<sitename>>"
        .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
        .Application.Selection = results.Sheets(1).Range("B2")
        .Application.Selection.EndOf

        'Transformer ID
        .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<TXname>>"
        .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
        .Application.Selection = results.Sheets(1).Range("B3")
        .Application.Selection.EndOf
    End With
End Sub

Sub PopulateReport()
    Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set wDoc = wApp.documents.Open("fileNameAndPath")
    wApp.Visible = True
    Call populateSite
End Sub
```

here is a [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLJDx.png) to part of the word doc

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to add

```
Set results = ActiveWorkbook
```

before calling the populateSite function.
After that the function works fine.

If this doesn't work, please send a screenshot of the word file.

Comment: I added that line but now it only deletes the <<sitename>> text and doesn't replace it with anything. I've included a screenshot in my edit

Comment: Have you tried to do a Search/Replace. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211953(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: I have ended up placing bookmarks throughout the word file and just replacing those. It's a lot more tedious but the macro is working fine. Thanks